# how to interpret this error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 164: ordinal not in range(128)"

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to run the below code in python 3:

```
def func(file):
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.html'):
                f = open(file, "r+")
                text  = re.sub(r'cat',' ', f.read())
                f.close()
                f = open(file, "w")
                f.write(text)
                f.close()

file = os.listdir(cwd)
func(file)
```

Then I got the error `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]`
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 164: ordinal not in range(128)`
The source is all in English, so not sure what is going on with here?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The source probably has a non-ascii character. Try another encoding.

Comment: HI @dabadaba, but it runs with python launcher...but I need to have it run from python IDE as well..

Comment: The IDE has nothing to do with this. You are reading from a file with a certain encoding, you need to configure the encoding when reading from that file so it is the proper one.

Comment: If I double click the script, it runs through python launcher successfully. But if I open the python file from IDE 3 and run it, the error shows up. I need to figure out how to change my python code to run it from IDE environment.

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the head of the file. Or try configuring the char encoding the IDE editor is using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found a way to solve this:

`f = open(file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode = "r+")`
`f = open(file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode = "w")`

it worked.